# How can I show just one content with 5 images

Tags: views, 8, search

I create search page with views in Drupal 8.

In filter criteria, I choose "Content: images:target_id" because I want show contents that have images. (I set *operator* to *not empty*.) If a node has 5 images, the search page show that node for 5 times.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: try using aggregation (if search views allows that).

Comment: @NoSssweat how can I using that ?

Comment: [see here](https://www.drupal.org/files/view3aggregation.png) and change No to Yes. idk if search views allows that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by using aggregation

[image]

Change the No to Yes.